# given $ D = {max} |a_i − b_i| <\epsilon$ . If $P(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k x^k$ has n distinct roots then $Q(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n b_k x^k$ has also

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_k \}^n_{k=0} $and $\{b_k \}^n_{k=0} $be two sets of n real numbers, and $ D = \underset {0 \leq i \leq n} {max} |a_i − b_i|$. Let $P(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k x^k$ and $Q(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n b_k x^k$ be polynomials. Show that if polynomial P has n distinct real roots, then there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such
that if $D < \epsilon $, then the polynomial Q has n distinct real roots.

Let $[-M, M]$ be an interval which contains all the roots of $P(x)$ with $M>1$.

Then $ \vert P(x)-Q(x) \vert \leq \vert a_1-b_1 \vert + \vert a_2-b_2 \vert \vert x \vert+ ... +\vert a_n-b_n \vert \vert x \vert^n \leq \vert T \vert^n \sum_{k=0}^{n} \vert a_k-b_k \vert$.

If $P$ has $n$ distinct roots then $P'(x)$ has $n-1$ distinct roots, by mean value theorem.

I am stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

If and only if a polynomial $R(x)$ has a multiple root, then the discriminant is $0$.  The discriminant can be described as a "Sylvester Determinant" of the coefficients of $R(x)$ and $R^\prime(x)$. Being a polynomial in the coefficients, the discriminant, is continuous, as is its absolute value. Call the discriminant of $P(x)$  $D_P$, and similar for $Q(x)$.  Suppose we choose $\delta$ such that $|D_P|>2\delta$ then we can choose $\epsilon$ such that $||D_P|-|D_Q||<\delta$, hence $|D_Q| >\delta$.